# Method from other class in if Statement not calling. Calls everywhere else fine

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Ok, when I call a method from CommandMethods (Another class) in an if statement the program terminates. But when I call it anywhere else, it works! I don't understand why it does that and I really want to know.

Code:

```
getCommand();

CommandMethods cm = new CommandMethods();

    if(Arrays.asList(commands[0]).equals(nextCommand)){
        cm.deauth();

    }else if(Arrays.asList(commands[1]).equals(nextCommand)){

        cm.exploit();


    }else if (Arrays.asList(commands[2]).equals(nextCommand)){

        cm.set();
    }
```

Can someone help me?

-Thanks

Edit:

Full code:

```
package ca.wax.main;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Wax {

static String commands[];
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static boolean containsCommand;
    static String nextCommand;
public static String getCommand(){ 

    do {
        nextCommand = s.nextLine();
        containsCommand = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
            if (commands[i].equals(nextCommand)) {
                containsCommand = true;
                return nextCommand;
            }    
        } 
        if (!containsCommand) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find command");
        }
        }while(!containsCommand);
    return null;
    }


public static void main(String[]args){

    CommandMethods cm = new CommandMethods();
    commands = new String[3];
    commands[0] = "deauth";
    commands[1] = "exploit";
    commands[2] = "set";



    System.out.println("Welcome to Wax!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Wax >");

    getCommand();
    if(Arrays.asList(commands[0]).equals(nextCommand)){
        cm.deauth();

    }else if(Arrays.asList(commands[1]).equals(nextCommand)){




    }else if (Arrays.asList(commands[2]).equals(nextCommand)){


    }







}

}
```

Comment: You are showing not enough code. Where are "commands" and nextCommand coming from? This code looks wrong on many many levels?!

Comment: Hint: you want us to help you, so you want to make that as easy as possible. For example: take the time and properly format your source code. Besides: this is really a very very bad idea: you do not let your user type commands as string. If at all, you print a list like ` command 1: deauth, command 2: ... ` to the user; and then you let him type the corresponding number.

Comment: And sorry, to say that: it really looks like most of your code is completely messed up. You are mixing static fields with local variables, you say that getCommand should return a string, but then your other code isn't using the  result of that call, but relies to find its information in those static fields. That's like horrible. You really should step back, and first read about the differences between static fields, and normal fields, and how methods are supposed to work in general.

Comment: Ok but how could it be bad my user could XSS my code?

Comment: You want to make it hard for the user to do the wrong thing. So, you a) tell him exactly which "options" he has; and b) you make it easy for him to select from them. But as said; the problem is that **most** of your code is a over complicated mess. Seriously, this can't be resolved on stack overflow. If possible, seek some real (more experienced) person around you, and sit down together and talk about your code.

Comment: Do you know where I can get that kind of help? I learned myself java....

Comment: User groups, peers in your school, college, neighborhood ... and if you are really disconnect from such options, don't try to teach yourself. Look out for "programs" that guide you, like https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java ... in other words: don't code your own solutions. Start with tutorials that go step by step ...

Comment: I have a java book that I read multiple times and I read a lot of Java docs